# Powershell Auto-Complete on ValidationSet

Tags: validation, powershell, user-interface

Creating a Validation Set is easy.

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateSet('Ding','Dong')]
[string]$bellState,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateSet('Dead','Alive')]
[string]$witchesState

)
```

It provides free auto completion if your Powershell version is >2
[image]

However it's not so helpful if you don't pass in the params at the start.

```
cmdlet Untitled2.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
bellState: Dib
witchesState: Alive
C:\Users\cac\Untitled2.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'bellState'. The argument "Dib" does not belong to the set "Ding,Dong" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then 
try the command again.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Untitled2.ps1],     ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Untitled2.ps1
```

This time there is no tab completion or clues :(

If you type in something invalid you do get a useful error:

```
"The argument "Dib" does not belong to the set "Ding,Dong""
```

However this error is thrown at the end of the params not at the time of the original mistake and there isn't an option to try again.

Has anyone found a way of extending this validation to be any more user friendly in the instance it initiated without passed in parameters.

Comment: I don't know a way to this using a ValidateSet extension. The only thing I know what would work is to use the `Read-Host` cmdlet and do it yourself but I wouldn't recommend that to you. You should probably live with it.

Answer (score 2):

While it might not be exactly what you wanted I would think a simple addition to the script would be to add HelpMessages to your parameters. That way the user has the option to get more information about what they are about to type.

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    HelpMessage="You need to pick ding or dong silly")]
[ValidateSet('Ding','Dong')]
[string]$bellState,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[ValidateSet('Dead','Alive')]
[string]$witchesState

)
```

So when called without specifying parameters...

```
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
bellState: !?
You need to pick ding or dong silly
bellState:
```

Comment: Exactly @Matt  I was just about to add this myself  see: [HelpMessage Argument](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx).  It isn't exactly what I wanted but it is better than leaving the user blind.  Just going to look at  Dynamic Parameters now.

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the mandatory bit and add some code after parameter block I can get the result I want.  I understand this might make a pretty useless Cmdlet for piping etc. so I see why it isn't default behavior.

I'm getting around this by having a function for doing the actual work with mandatory params and having a separate helper function to get user input.

It's not so long winded or tricky to get the following to do pretty much whatever you want.

There's an [article here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx)

```
 if(!($bellState)){
        $title = "Pick a Bell State"
        $message = "You need to pick ding or dong silly"

        $Ding = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Ding", `
            "First Strike."

        $Dong = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "Dong", `
            "Second Strike."

        $options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Ding, $Dong)

        $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

        switch ($result)
            {
                0 { $type = "Ding" ; "First Strike."}
                1 { $type = "Dong" ; "Second Strike."}
            }

 }
```